# How can I map correctly a model in a model in EF Core 5?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a Recipe object which looks like this(all of the code is a simplified sample):

```cs
public class Recipe
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(4000)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual ICollection<RecipeIngredient> Ingredients { get; set; } = new List<RecipeIngredient>();
}
```

As you can see my Recipe object has a List of RecipeIngredient which looks like this:

```cs
public class RecipeIngredient
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int IngredientId { get; set; }
    public Ingredient Ingredient { get; set; }

    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

I needed this new RecipeIngredient model to be able to track how much of each ingredient is needed in the recipe.

The thing is, I have a controller where I try to return every recipe in a list like this:

```cs
// GET: api/Recipes
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Recipe>>> GetRecipes()
{
    return await _context.Recipes.Include(m => m.Ingredients).ToListAsync();
    //return await _context.Recipes.ToListAsync();
}
```

As you can see there is a commented part where I don't include the Ingredients list in the model (but I have to get them too) and it works so clearly this include part is the wrong one.

Do you have any idea? I am not sure how to map this, or if introducing a new model is the proper fix for my problem

Comment: You include only RecipeIngredient, not ingredient. To include RecipeIngredient and Ingredient, you need `_context.Recipes.Include(r => r.Ingredients).ThenInclude(ri => ri.Ingredient)...`. But I will subject to add a proper model to your API.

Comment: From EF Core 5, you can set up many-to-many relationship without relation entity : [Official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#many-to-many)

Comment: "_so clearly this include part is the wrong one_" - may be, but we can tell only if we know what result exactly are you expecting? How does your JSON result should look like?

Comment: @atiyar So I have a Recipe object which has to store ingredients with the quantity needed of them. So I created a RecipeIngredient model where I have an Ingredient with the Recipe it belongs to. So I want to get all my recipes and all the ingredients needed. So it would look like this: ` recipe:{"id": 0, "description:"...", "Ingredients": [RecipeIngredient objects]} ` hope it clears what I need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the result you are expecting should look like (as you mentioned in the comment) -

```
recipe:{"id": 0, "description:"...", "Ingredients": [RecipeIngredient objects]}
```

then your query should look like -

```
await _context.Recipes
        .Include(p => p.Ingredients)
        .ThenInclude(p => p.Ingredient)
        .ToList();
```